# Proper way to have a list of sync or async methods called in a safe manner

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a use case where I made an `EventManager` class that essentially have two methods. One takes a method pointer in the form of an `Action<eventType>` to register that method pointer as one of many handlers for `eventType`. I pass both "normal" methods and async methods to this.
The other takes an instance of an `eventType` as a signal to raise that event and call all the previously registered handlers.

When an event is raised, I call all the handlers based on their `methodInfo` and invoke them one by one. I do not await *any* of them, and treat all the same, even though some are sync and some are async, and that all works well... or so it seemed for a long time.

While I have extensively used the async pattern, there are apparently still details which can kick me in the head at times, and things I am simply unaware of, and I have for a while had issues with random uncaught exceptions, which I am pretty sure comes from this implementation.

After seeking some more advice on good and bad async here, I have redesigned so I can pass either an `Action<eventType>` or a `Func<Task, eventType>`, and store it as `methodInfo` so I can later properly invoke *and await* the call when it is an async method.

I made a proof of concept, which seems to work correctly, before making sweeping changes in the live project, and would like if someone with more async insight than myself could comment on this. Is this in fact proper and safe now, or am I just headed into a whole other set of problems?

It is a very simplified test case demonstrating the core of my new system. Somewhere you call the `eventManager` to register a method to handle some event and elsewhere someone else calls the `eventManager` to raise the event, and the manager calls all relevant handlers while trying to await the async ones. All is running main thread.

In this example, all of this is represented by the `Test()` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    public static class ext
    {
        public static async Task InvokeAsync(this MethodInfo @this, object obj, params object[] parameters)
        {
            dynamic awaitable = @this.Invoke(obj, parameters);
            if (awaitable!=null) await awaitable;            
        }
    }

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(); //what is the proper way to start´this async chain from a non async method?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //a description of an event handler containing the method and object to handle it
    private struct RegistredEventHandler
    {
        public object HandlerObject;
        public MethodInfo HandlerMethod;
    }

    //list of all registered handlers
    private static List<RegistredEventHandler> handlerList = new List<RegistredEventHandler>();

    //first async method in the chain doing both the registering and the raising of events as a simple test
    private static async Task Test()
    {
        //register an event handler for both the async and the serial method

        Func<int, Task> asyncFunc = TestAsync;
        var hAsync = new RegistredEventHandler()
        {
            HandlerObject = asyncFunc.Target,
            HandlerMethod = asyncFunc.Method
        };
        handlerList.Add(hAsync);

        Action<int> serialAction = TestSerial;
        var hSerial = new RegistredEventHandler()
        {
            HandlerObject = serialAction.Target,
            HandlerMethod = serialAction.Method
        };
        handlerList.Add(hSerial);

        //try invoking and awating both handlers
        foreach (var eventHandler in handlerList)
        {
            await eventHandler.HandlerMethod.InvokeAsync(eventHandler.HandlerObject, new object[] { 10});
        }
    }
    static void TestSerial(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Serial argument {i}");
    }

    static async Task TestAsync(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Async argument {i}");
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `if(eventHandler is Func<....>)`

Comment: Taking the `Target` and `Method` properties of a delegate is incomplete... You need to call `GetInvocationList` to get all target/method pairs attached to the delegate instance, not just one of them. But that's something delegates do really well already. You could declare `handlerList` as `List<Delegate>`.

Comment: @pm100 Instead of doing what? Not sure I follow.

Comment: @madreflection The Action or Func, I pass, is always just one single method.

Comment: That may be so, but those are two separate points I made.  Even if you can guarantee that you will never have just one invocation in the delegate, the second point is that you're still reinventing the wheel.

Comment: A `Delegate` instance can be invoked using `DynamicInvoke` (since both signatures have the same parameters and only the return type differs), or as pm100 suggested, test for the two types and invoke statically (either `f(x);` or `f.Invoke(x);`). So if you have a `List<Delegate>`, you can iterate through those and invoke them either of those two ways and you don't have to build infrastructure that duplicates what delegates already do.

Comment: Ok,thanks,fair enough. I could do that,instead of my own lists. My main worry is about any async exception issues with this approach,though.

Comment: If you have a delegate that returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`, you need to call `GetInvocationList` in your extension method, construct an array of tasks containing the tasks returned by invoking all of them, and then use `Task.WhenAll` to await *all* of them. If the delegate returns `Task<T>`, the extension method should return a `Task<T[]>` containing all the results. Funny, it's fresh for me because I recently wrote exactly this kind of extension method based on another question I saw.